# Having to create a .nuxt folder every time I compile my app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Every time I run `npm run dev`(that's how my team set up that project) I get this error:

> ERROR EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'X:......\my-project\.nuxt'

I then need to do `mkdir .nuxt` and try again. Usually it works, sometimes it doesn't: it keeps asking me that everytime I run `npm run dev` and after 5 or 10 times it works. Sometimes I won't work no matter how many times I try, so I restart my machine and then it works.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What's in the dev script?

Comment: In `package.json`: `"scripts": { "dev": "nuxt", ... }`. Let me know if you want to know other things as well.

Comment: So it's just calling `nuxt`? Does `nuxt` work consistently if you run it directly?

Comment: [This post](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2109) may be relevant. I don't use nuxt, so I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find a solution there though.

Comment: Could we also see in the answer the `nuxt.config.js` files? Or anything that is part of the dev process?

Comment: Could you tell what part of the file you'd like to see in particular? (I'd rather not paste the entire content, not sure my employer would agree with that)

Answer (score 2):

I have had issues of this kind when running in the past with gulp in parallel tasks that would delete and write to the same deleted directory. But, without having more information about this, and just knowing that sometimes the `.nuxt` directory is missing. I can't really get to the root of the problem. It might be something related with the `nuxt.config.js`

This is the only solution that I see for now.

Even though this might not fix the original issue what you could do to at least be able to develop without having to worry any longer is:

- Add the [`rimraf` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) and run it always before running the `dev` command.
- Add the [`mkdirp` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) and run it after the deletion of the folder happen

If you add the commands globally now you should have in your terminal both commands available and you can run

`rimraf ./.nuxt && mkdirp .nuxt && npm run dev`

This would be the least intrusive approach as it wouldn't affect any of your team members.

If also they are affected by this you can also add this packages as a `devDependency` and add another `npm run dev` command as shown here.

```
{
...
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "rimraf ./.nuxt && mkdirp .nuxt && npm run dev"
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I installed both packages globally then ran `rimraf ./.nuxt && mkdirp .nuxt && npm run dev`, but the same problem still occurs...

Comment: Could you show me which is the dev process for the `nuxt.config.js` ? I feel like there's something parallel there that is deleting and writing at the same time :)

Comment: There's no mention of "dev" at all in `nuxt.config.js` actually